# Modifying component variable on on click event highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am modifying some variable of chart component which uses highcharts inside. 
Basically work of my chart component is to make dynamic configuration for highchart. Suppose my chart has a variable `vm.showSomething=false` and on onclick function i change its value to `true`, but it doesn't reflect it in my chart component,it remains `false`. Is there  any way to achieve this i tried callback function but same result, i don't want to fire event and catch it in chart component.

```
vm.doSomething = doSomething;
function doSomething(){
   vm.something = true;
}
//this is config inside chart component which is sent to highchart
function initConfig(){
    config.plotOptions.series = {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click:function () {
                    vm.doSomething();//variable of chart component, i tried call back function also but result is same
                }
            }
        }
    }};
}
```

here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Lzbxrht7/2/

found the solution used $scope.$apply();

Comment: hey georgeawg  have edited my question little bit if it helps. Problem is this my chart component is really big, and it doesn't do anything other than preparing config for highchart. If it is still not clear i will create and example on jsfiddle.